# Subscribe to a Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, objective-c-blocks

Im building some iOS SDK where in my requirement is that, 
I want to subscribe a block when ever certain value changes, and i
need to obtain a subscription object exposing a cancel method. The block will receive new change value on every 60s until, **either:**

- The cancel method is invoked.
- The last strong reference for the subscription method has been released (the client should keep a mapping of weak references to subscription objects to their respective blocks).

How can I achieve the above scenario and what is the approach i need to follow:
I need to build it using the Objective-c.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have any code that you could show us

Comment: No i do not have any as such, Its just the overview of what i need to build!!
So im thinking of what is the approach i need to follow!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check out [ReactiveObjC](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveObjC) for a great way to deal with subscribers which can manage the lifetime of the subscription by disposing of the signal.